# Is the relative path for a java project different for Intellij and cmd?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a java assignment, and at a specific point, we have to create a new folder and write some text files there. The issue is, when testing my code on Intellij, it works fine, but when testing it on cmd, I need to change it a tad bit?

My project structure:

```
.../project/src/greedycomparisons  // greedycomparisons is the file where I'm creating the dir from
.../projct/data                    // the directory I want to create, to have my text files in
```

More specifically:

I'm trying to create the new subdirectory from a file I have inside my src folder. Therefore, the thing I tried first was:

```
File directory = new File("./data/");
if (!directory.mkdir()) dosth;    // nothing happens on first call
/* making the String I want as my file's name, say string */
File file = new File(directory, string);
```

Which works fine (on Intellij), creating the subdirectory (and the files later on) exactly where I want them to. And then, likewise, I try accessing the files I made there from another file in my src folder, by again using "./data" before the name of the file I was trying to access, which again works as expected on Intellij.

But when I tested this on cmd, I need to change the directory name to "../data" in order for the code to work, which in turn *does not work on Intellij* (specifically giving me a "The system could not find the path specified" error) when I change it to that. Given that I have to submit it as an assignment and I don't want any ambiguity in regards to my files, is there something more "universal" that I can try, so my code works regardless?

Comment: You can't use relative paths for writes in deployed apps. Apps are deployed as jars and you have no means of knowing where that will end up, nor *from where* it will be run. If you need to write data, create a dedicated directory off $user.home

Comment: What folder are you in when you run it from `cmd`?

Answer (score 0):

If you check your IntelliJ configuration, by clicking at the top where you have the name of the file you are executing, you can click on Edit Configurations, and you will see one of the fields you can configure, called "Working directory".

IntelliJ is smart enough to set it to your project folder, outside the `/src` folder, because it is not good practice to write data inside your `/src` folder which should only have source files, unless they are resources you want to commit with your code.

On the other hand, when executing it from `cmd`, your working directory is just where you are trying to run the compiled program from. You haven't specified in which folder you are in when doing so, but most probably you are inside some subfolder that has the classes, which is why you needed to do the `..`.

If you package your classes in a `.jar` file, the way IntelliJ made it should work. If you run your `.jar` file with `java -jar myjarfile.jar` and the `./data` folder is at the same level, then it would work.

Comment: Of course, 'normal' users don't tend to run Java apps from the command line. They run them by double-clicking on an icon, so if you're determined to use relative paths to data output, the shortcut might have to have the current working directory specified too. That would probably be too technical to expect from the user.

Comment: thank you both very much for your input. Yeah that was certainly it, I'm tinkering with it a tad more now and I see that it was impossible to get it to run from both cmd and an IDE as it was, and I needed to do this.

Thank you both very much, have a nice day!

Comment: @g00se 'normal' users don't run Java applications on their desktop :)

Comment: There are many Java apps for the desktop.

Comment: @g00se apart from IDEs and a few programming tools, there are very few successful ones. Java is mostly successful on the serverside. But anyway, beyond the point of this question.

Comment: I'm sorry but your assertion that normal people don't run Java desktop programs is simply not accurate. You might even find that more than a few Minecraft users might be a little insulted.

Comment: @g00se My assertion is based on 20 years of experience with Java, starting with Swing and little bit JavaFX. I didn't say they didn't exist. I am saying they are very rare. Java client applications are horrible, and if you are going to start a new (serious) desktop application and you opt for Java you are insane. On the other hand, if you want to use Java on the serverside, with frameworks like Spring Boot, that is where it is strong and offers the best advantages.